# How to access a private Map in JUnit using reflections?

Tags: java, testing, reflection, junit

I have a connector class (SVNConnector) which should be junit tested. There is a private map called `private Map<String, SVNRepository> connectionMap` which should be accessed in JUnit, but this map doesn't have a getter method. So I have to use reflections to do that. My question is: How does that work? I tried the following:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    svnConnector = new SVNConnector(user, pwd);
    Field connectionMapField = SVNConnector.class.getDeclaredField("connectionMap");
    connectionMapField.setAccessible(true);
//AND NOW?
}
```

There are not any Collection specific getters or setters to check the size of the collectionMap or similar. So how can I access it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean you want to get the value of the field?

```
Map<String, SVNRepository> connectionMap = 
    (Map<String, SVNRepository>) connectionMapField.get(svnConnector);
```

Answer (score 1):

Obtain the reference form the field (by using the [Field.get(Object](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)) method), cast it to Map and then use it.

```
Map connectionMap = (Map) connectionMapField.get(svnConnector);

int size = connectionMap.getSize();
```

*You may also should have a look at the [Java Reflection Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).*

Answer (score 1):

Check out JUnit-addons.

Particularly - http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/util/PrivateAccessor.html

With the main page here - http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/

For example:

```
PrivateAccessor.setField(myClassInstance, "privateMapName", myMap);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like to use additional libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Had you liked to use additional libraries (and annotation processors) you could have used [dp4j](http://www.junit.org/node/591)'s  `@TestPrivate`s annotation:

```
    @TestPrivates
    @BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    svnConnector = new SVNConnector(user, pwd);
    Map<String, SVNRepository> connectionMap = svnConnector.connectionMap; 
/* dp4j will replace this plain access the equivalent Reflection API code at compile-time */
    }
```

You can also use the `-Averbose` option to see the generated Reflection code, copy-paste it, and then remove `@TestPrivates`